# Connecting to MySQL from Python using sqlalchemy, mysql+mysqldb works on Windows+Ubuntu but not RHEL

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, odbc, redhat

Thanks for taking the time to read through this question.
I've spent quite a bit of time trying to find an answer to this and some time digging through code in `pydobc` and `mysqldb` to no avail.

### Summary of Problem:

I can connect to a MySQL server using the same method+connection string from many machines, but cannot use the same method from a RHEL server. I continually get an `Access denied` error; it seems unlikely this is actually the issue though.

### Background:

I am using `sqlalchemy` to connect to a MySQL server hosted on a remote network. I am able to connect to the MySQL server using the same credentials from MySQL Workbench, MySQL Shell, my local Jupyter Notebook, local Python scripts, a virtual Ubuntu 18.04 WSL1 instance, *and* the troublesome RHEL server- **but I cannot use the same connection method on RHEL as the rest of the instances.**

I am positive my user has access to read/write tables on the MySQL server (and ostensibly make ODBC connections since I believe I'm doing so from my laptop), so despite the error below, I'm having a hard time believing it is *actually* a true permission error. That said, I'm happy to listen to any suggestions.

### Problem:

When connecting from any of the sources listed above except for the RHEL server, I am able to utilize this code to create an engine and subsequently a connection:

```py
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://{user}:{password}@{server}:{port}/{database}?charset=utf8mb4'.format(user=user
                                ,password=password
                                ,server=server
                                ,port=port
                                ,database=database))

con = engine.connect()
```

I am then able to use that connection to do any number of things- `pd.to_sql()`, direct code executions- works like a charm.

The issue comes up when I try to use that same connection info on the RHEL Server, I get the following error:

```py
>>> engine.connect()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python_dir/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3211, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/python_dir/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 307, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/python_dir/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 767, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/python_dir/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 425, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/python_dir/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/python_dir/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/python_dir/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/python_dir/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/python_dir/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 253, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/python_dir/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 368, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/python_dir/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 611, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/python_dir/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/python_dir/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/python_dir/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 605, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/python_dir/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 578, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/python_dir/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 584, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/python_dir/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/python_dir/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'USER'@'SERVER_ADDRESS' (using password: YES)")
```

Obviously I've changed a few things in the error for security, but that last line is the only real error I see:

```py
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'USER'@'SERVER_ADDRESS' (using password: YES)")
```

### Connecting from RHEL

Despite the failure using the connection info above, I *am* able to connect to the MySQL server from the RHEL server with a different connection setup:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pyodbc://my_dsn')
```

By using pyodbc, I'm able to connect utilizing a DSN (I think DSN is the right term- this is getting a bit murky for me) that I have configured on the RHEL server in `/etc/odbc.ini`
Here's an example of what I have for that specific entry (I've retained capitalizations + blanks where they exist in the file, but have changed all sensitive fields):

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
my_dsn = My Special DSN

[my_dsn]
Driver = /dir/libmyodbc5.so
Description = Description
SERVER = Server
PORT = Port
USER = User
Password = Password
Database = Database
OPTION = 3
SOCKET =
```

The only major difference that I see between the DSN configuration listed above and the connection string that I'm providing to `mysqldb` is that the DSN lets me specify the `OPTION` parameter. I can't figure out *how* `pyodbc` uses this, though.

I've tried digging through the documentation from quite a few sources (`sqlalchemy`,`pyodbc`,`MySQL`,StackOverflow,SuperUser, direct source code) to find if/how to specify the `OPTION` for `mysqldb` to no avail. I'm not sure if that `OPTION` is really making that big of a difference, but it's the only piece I can't provide.

That being said, I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333668/mysql-connector-odbc-odbc-ini-option-flag-values) that explains what the options are a bit more and [this corresponding page](http://web.archive.org/web/20051224022017/http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/connection-parameters.html) that the answer came from. Although that doesn't help me much.

### Goal

Ideally, I'd like to be able to run my connections the exact same regardless of server or OS. I'm not sure if that's possible, but it's what I'm attempting to do. I would rather not set up the same DSN on every machine that needs to connect (so the `pyodbc` option I'm using on RHEL isn't ideal), but no other connection method from that RHEL server will work.

### Troubleshooting

I don't have a stellar understanding of the drivers/Linux config, so there's definitely a possibility that I've done something wrong here. Here's some stuff I've tried:

- Tried many different connection strings and different drivers/connection info specified
- Tried installing various different MySQL drivers on RHEL (with varied success)
- Read dozens of questions and articles on similar issues
- Other janky configuration attempts that didn't help
- Wept softly over my keyboard

### Configuration Information:

- Problem server: RHEL Version 7
- Other machines: Ubuntu 18.04, Windows 10
- Python: 3.8
- `SQLAlchemy`: RHEL- 1.4.20, Windows- 1.4.15, Ubuntu- 1.4.22
- `pyodbc`: RHEL- 4.0.30, Windows- 4.0.30, Ubuntu- 4.0.31

If I can provide any more information, please let me know! Really appreciate any ideas.

Comment: see ig the user has the grants.

Comment: Looking at [mysql odbc downloads](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) the `libmyodbc8[aw].so` is the file not `libmyodbc5`. It looks like your version is really old. So the MySQL-8.0 authentication isn't understood by the earlier drivers. [docs](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-MySQL) reference ANSI.  I'm note sure why you chose ODBC over MySQL Connector/Python, PyMySQL or other [SQL Alchemy DBAPI Drivers](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html).

Comment: If above doesn't help put the MySQL version, the odbc version, and `show create user {username}` in your question. And like @nbk suggested `show grants for {user}`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue may be that your RHEL server is setup to require SSL and you haven't specified to only use SSL in your connection.   I always setup my database servers to require SSL and have encountered plenty of situations where "require SSL" was not configured.  MySQL is notorious for only letting you know "Access denied" when you are attempting to connect without SSL.

Try adding `connect_args={'sslmode': "require"}` to your create_engine args

Note: the exact args to specify to require SSL depends on your connector.  I *think* the mysqldb connector uses "sslmode".    I usually use pymysql and it requires `connect_args={"ssl":{"ssl_disabled":False}}`